# If time is before or after specific time display good morning/good afternoon?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, but basically looking to display a particularly welcome message depending on the current time.

For example, before 12 display Good Morning

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
final String message = DateTime.now().hour < 12 ? "Good morning" : "Good afternoon";
```

Comment: Thank you! Thought it would be something easy, will mark as correct answer after time is up

Answer (score 5):

For current time get,

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; 

DateTime now = DateTime.now();

print(now.hour.toString() + ":" + now.minute.toString() + ":" + now.second.toString());
```

After time get you just check conditions for time.
Like

**Good morning**

- 12 AM to 11:59 AM
- (12 to 11:59) in 24 hour format

**Good afternoon**

- 12PM to 4:59PM
- (24 to 16:59) in 24 hour format

**Good evening**

- 5PM to 7:59PM
- (17 to 19:59) in 24 hour format

**Good night**

- 8PM to 11:59 PM
- (20 to 22:59) in 24 hour format

After that just check by simple condition,

```
    String greeting = ""; 
    int hours=now.hour;


    if(hours>=1 && hours<=12){ 
    greeting = "Good Morning"; 
    } else if(hours>=12 && hours<=16){
     greeting = "Good Afternoon"; 
    } else if(hours>=16 && hours<=21){ 
    greeting = "Good Evening";
     } else if(hours>=21 && hours<=24){ 
    greeting = "Good Night"; 
    }

Print("your message:-"+greeting);
```